# How to make the credential argument for .reauthenticateWithCredential() in firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

To delete/edit the information of a user in firebase auth, you need to have recently logged in. This can be done with .reauthenticateWithCredential(). How can I make the credential for this (using email auth) in javascript? I have tried with (email, password) and ({email, password}), but no luck.

Code:

```
function reauth() {
        const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.auth.email, password);

        user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(function() {
                firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).delete().then(() => {
                    user.delete().then(function() {
                        navigation.replace("Signup")
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, according to the doc it should be credential(email, password). What problem do you have? Do you receive any exception?

Comment: With the code above I get this error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.auth.email') and with user.reauthenticateWithCredential(email, password) I get that it has to be one argument.

Comment: it sounds like 2 errors. for email, isn't it user.email (without auth)? Then it is credential(email, password), and reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).

Comment: That sounds like a solution! I'll try it when my computer and me has gotten some rest tomorrow. I'll let you know!

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (Web v9)

```js
import {
  EmailAuthProvider, getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const onReaAuth = () => {
  const passowrd = "from user input";
  const auth = getAuth();
  const { currentUser } = auth;
  const { email } = currentUser;
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
  
  reauthenticateWithCredential(currentUser, credential)
   .then(() => {
     console.log('done')
    }
 }
```